# Homepage design : dynamically moving and expanding images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to update my start-up company's website' homepage, but my knowledge in programming is limited to HTML, CSS, a little bit of jQuery, and I am trying to understand HTML5 (I can also read~ish Javascript, but it's not often a great success...)!
Therefore i am coming to you for a solution.

Here's the following (picture enclosed) :

- The logo is here, no need to touch that ;)
- what i need is for the smallbox.png (with some "CAR" written on it) to get a glow when hovered on with the mouse (i got the smallbox_glow.png)
- then move to the middle of the page (1) when clicked on (still same image, with car written on it)
- then automatically fade the text away, expand into the big box (2) and get some different text (..about cars) to fade in.

Is this impossible to do, or 2 lines or code will make it work? I am kind of stuck here...

I am willing (and interested!) to learn different coding languages, so shoot away with the complexity if necessary =)

Image :

here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eikh7.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, this isn't a code writing service; try it for yourself and come back when you have a question or problem with a specific part of the implementation.

Comment: You're question is likely to be closed as this isn't constructive. At least have a go first and then come back with code snippets you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Anthony 100%...here are some pointers to get you started.

Per your use case

1. what i need is for the smallbox.png (with some "CAR" written on it) to get a glow when hovered on with the mouse (i got the smallbox_glow.png)
2. then move to the middle of the page (1) when clicked on (still same image, with car written on it)
3. then automatically fade the text away, expand into the big box (2) and get some different text (..about cars) to fade in.

Some food for thought:

1. This can be done via CSS alone using background-images for anchors and change via a:hover and/or a:active, etc.  If it is plain text that you are displaying, consider using "text-shadow" for your glow effects and modernizer.js for cross-platform compatibility.
2. This can be done using HTML canvas or [jQuery's animate api](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
3. [jQuery offers various fade effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

As we are all new at some point, don't be shy to post what you have as we can better assist with any questions.

Best of luck.